# offsetWidth is returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, html, css, offsetwidth

Okay so I'm attempting to make a horizontal site but when I try getting the offsetWidth of the navigation, it returns a value far higher than the true width. The design in question can be found [here](http://jordan-adams.co.uk/2012/3/). The CSS for the page is [here](http://jordan-adams.co.uk/2012/3/assets/css/base3.css) and the JS [here](http://jordan-adams.co.uk/2012/3/assets/js/events.js).

Many thanks to anyone who can work this out :)

Comment: Can you do some console.log-ing and see what the values are on page load? Because I load your page, and see that the box is too wide, but then if I run that function after page load it works properly. Also, add a +40 to the end of the pnW variable (to account for the margin)

Comment: Your links are broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your page looks like just moment before CSS is applied:
http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/1047/shotjt.png . In that moment width of #projects nav is width of client screen.

You have two solutions:

1. specify width of #projects nav in style attribute
2. add some timeout to the init JS function: domready(function() { setTimeout("initPageFunction()", 200); }

Surprisingly, it works good in IE :)

Comment: Thanks :) In the end I used a window load event instead of domready

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is set the body margin to 0, usually when no width is set and the body margin is untouched, the render might be off by 16 pixels which accounts for 8 pixels to each side (left and right) of the body tag.

Rodrigo.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the space created by margins are calculated, and there's a right margin for the last article. Here's the fixed script.

```
domready(function() {

    var projectsContainer = qwery('#projects')[0];
    var projects = qwery('.project');
    var projectsNav = qwery('#projects nav')[0];

    var pMargin = 40;
    var pnW = projectsNav.offsetWidth+cMargin;

    for(p in projects) {
        projects[p].style.marginRight = pMargin+'px';
    }

    projectsContainer.style.width = (projects.length*(projects[0].offsetWidth+pMargin))+pnW+'px';

});
```